# Segmentation fault, scanf

Tags: c, scanf

We have an assignment which is to take characters from a file, shift it a given value to the right(it'll make sense in the  code) and then store that new value in a new file, but I seem to be running into a segmentation fault, which as far as I know means I'm trying to access memory outside of the memory I have been allocated? I'm very new to C and I managed to debug this code up until this point and I honestly don't know where to go. I don't even quite understand what the issue is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//Get Shift amount
//Get ifilename
//Get ofilename
//open them
//Get characters one at a time from input
//Process and shift by shift amount
int main()
{
    int i;//loop value
    char a[62]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";//Variable with every value
    int sa = 0;//Store Shift value
    char ofile[30];//contain the name of output file
    char ifile[30];//contain name of input file
    char value;//Value to keep the current value in

    printf("How far in ascii values would you like to shift?\n");
    scanf("%i", sa);//Get shift
    printf("What is the name of your input file located in this directory?");
    scanf("%s", ifile);//get input name
    printf("What would you like to name your new file?\n Do note that it will overwrite the current file named this!");
    scanf("%s", ofile);//Get output name

    FILE *oIfile = fopen(ifile, "r"), *oOfile = fopen(ofile, "w");

    while(value = fscanf(oIfile, "%c", value) != EOF)//Check to ensure that you never reach the end of the file
    {
        for(i=0; i<62; i++)//loop through the list of all characters
        {
            if(value == a[i])//check to see if the value from the input file matches with which letter
            {
                value = a[i+sa] % 62;//incrase the value by the shift amount, check if its longer than 62, add remainder
                break;//break the for loop so we can restart the while loop with the next letter
            }
        }
        fprintf(oOfile, "%c");//print the new value to the output file
    }
    fclose(oIfile);//close input file
    fclose(oOfile);//close output file
}
```

is this issue due to my approach to scanf?

Comment: `a[i+sa]` looks like you could easily step out of bounds here. Maybe you wanted to mod before the array lookup?

Comment: "im on a deadline". I am sorry, I fell for you, but the posts in this site are meant to be timeless. The urgency of your task is not of concern here.

Comment: Just for future reference, segmentation faults are due to memory issues - the code is either reading or writing an illegal memory location. This could be reading from a file that doesn't exist, or, as in this case, trying to write input to address "0", as opposed to the address of the int `sa`.

Comment: @bolov Re:  Just 1 letter makes for a humorous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816082/segmentation-fault-scanf#comment84636167_48816082): [I fell for you](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fall-for) vs. [I feel for you](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/238417/51392)

Comment: @chux well, what can I say, urgency is sexy? :)

Comment: Note well the general point: myFunc(arg) cannot modify arg.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from passing the address to `scanf` `(scanf("%i",&sa)` which you would have to do (Also it would be correct to check the return value of it) - you need to correct a few things:-

- It should be `(value = fscanf(oIfile, "%c", value)) != EOF`. `!=` has higher precedence than `=` so this is needed to get the correct result.
- Also `a[(i+sa)%62]=...` is the right way to do things. Because otherwise it will access array index out of bound for certain values of `sa` leading to undefined behavior.
- `fprintf(stream,"%c",charvariable)` this would be the use for `fprintf`.
- The `value` is over written with what is being returned by the value that `fscanf` returns. You should use other temporary variable or even better simply do like this `while(fscanf(oIfile, "%c", value)!=EOF)`. But to have more checks you need to do somehting like

  ```
    int c;
    while((c=fscanf(oIfile, "%c", value))!=EOF)
  ```

You got segmentation fault here by passing the value of `sa` instead of its address in `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` take an address as a parameter.  Try this;

```
scanf("%i", &sa);//Get shift
```